# CORS error when POST data in AngularJS & CodeIgniter3

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm use AngularJS 1.3 and CodeIgniter 3.0.

I success to GET data from php in localhost.
However I have error "Cross-origin-request blocked".
I do not know it but was a search, plese help me.

Javascript

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
module.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});

module.controller('MasterController', function($scope, $http) {    
$scope.doLogin = function() {
    var postData = {"email": "aaa@bbb.ccc", "password": "pass"};
    var url = 'http://example/test?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

    //This section is Error
    $http.post(url, postData, {withCredentials: true})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //
    });

    //This section is Success
    $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //
    });
};
});
```

I tried "$http({url ~})", but It was the same result.

PHP

```
public function index() {
    $input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
    $this->output
    ->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
    ->set_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($input_data));
}
```

Comment: Can you share 'test'  function, where you post from angular?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `.htaccess` to allow CORS. Put this in your server .htaccess file

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even accessing different port is perceived by browser as cross-domain action, the best guide so far how to enable CORS can be found here http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it did not improve.
I'll try to find another way while looking that site.